# How can I access the list values returned from the controller from ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jsp, post

I'm returning a list from my controller. How can I access these list values from AJAX? I get undefined when I make an alert.

**Controller**

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/practice/{category}/option", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public List<Map<String, Object>> practicePageOption(@PathVariable("category") String category, @RequestParam("index") int index, ModelMap model, HttpSession session){

    //System.out.println(optionsList.get(index));
    //Result;
    //[{word=abdomen, meaning=karın}, {word=search, meaning=aramak}, {word=fund, meaning=kurmak}, {word=surgeon, meaning=cerrah}, {word=various, meaning=çeşitli}]
    return optionsList.get(index);
}
```

**AJAX:**

```
$('#pass').click(function(event) {
    var inputIndex = $('#index').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/practice/${category}",
        async:false,
        data: { index: inputIndex },
        success: function(data){
            $('#label').text(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/practice/${category}/option",
                async:false,
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType:"json",
                data: { index: inputIndex },
                complete: function (data) {
                    //how can use data value
                    $('#optionA').text(data[0]);
                    alert(data[0]);  //undefined
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I see you are accessing a value on the form with var inputIndex = $('#index').val(); . Add the form to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your javascript. For the second ajax request you use the **complete** property instead of **success**. The function specified in the complete property should have the following signature: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus ) so instead of your json list you are receiving a  [jquery XHR object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) that's why data[0] is undefined. If you want your list then you should get it like this:

```
var myList = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
alert(myList[0]);
```